# datatables not binding Json with columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

Here is my code

```
oTable = $('#userlisttable')
                            .dataTable(
                                    {
                                        "serverSide" : false,
                                        "ajax" : {
                                            "url" : context + "user/get",
                                        },
                                        "columns" : [ {
                                            "data" : "username"
                                        }, {
                                            "data" : "userpassword"
                                        }, {
                                            "data" : "usertype"
                                        }, {
                                            "data" : "firstname"
                                        }, {
                                            "data" : "lastname"
                                        }, {
                                            "data" : "emailaddress"
                                        }, {
                                            "data" : "isactive"
                                        }, ],


                                        "columnDefs" : [ {
                                            "targets" : "7",
                                            "data" : "userId",
                                            "render" : function(data, type,
                                                    full, meta) {
                                                return '<a href="#" id="row'
                                                        + data
                                                        + '" class="btn btn-success" onclick="callModal(id)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit icon-white"></i>EDIT</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" id="row'
                                                        + data
                                                        + '" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="callDeleteModal(id)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash icon-white"></i>Deactivate</a>';
                                            }
                                        } ],

                                        "sDom" : 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
                                        "oTableTools" : {
                                            "sRowSelect" : "single",
                                            "sSwfPath" : "../../resources/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
                                              "aButtons": [
                                                            "csv" 
                                                        ]
                                        }

                                    });
```

server returns following Json

```
[{"password":"password","username":"user","lastAccess":1408089626000,"creationDate":1408089626000,"userId":1,"lastName":"reddy","isActive":"y","firstName":"manjari","email":"man@gmail.com","isLdap":"y","ldapQuery":"query","accessType":"any","usertype":"admin"}]
```

but data is not dislpled in datatable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [doc on the ajax option](http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) (scroll down to the examples) :

> Get JSON data from a file via Ajax, using dataSrc to read data from a plain array rather than an array in an object:
>
> ```
> $('#example').dataTable( {
>   "ajax": {
>     "url": "data.json",
>     "dataSrc": ""   
>    } 
> } );
> ```